# Using DetachedCriteria to return generic list of non-AR type

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord, detachedcriteria

I'm fiddling with my repository class and attempted to execute a query with a detached criteria. However, it doesn't seem to like me setting the result transformer to a non AR-type.

```
public class IncidentRepository
{
    public static IList<AuditReport> GetAllIncidentsToAudit()
    {
        DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.For<Incident>("i")
            .SetProjection(
                Projections.ProjectionList()
                    .Add(Projections.Property("i.Id"), "IncidentId")
                    .Add(Projections.Property("l.Id"), "LocationId")
            )
            .CreateCriteria("Locations", "l")
                .Add(Expression.Eq("l.PrimaryLocationFlag", "T"))
            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<AuditReport>());

        return ActiveRecordMediator<AuditReport>.FindAll(dc);
    }
}

public class AuditReport
{
    public int IncidentId { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
}
```

The error I get when executing this query is:

```
You have accessed an ActiveRecord class that wasn't properly initialized. There are two possible explanations: that the call to ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize() didn't include castle.AuditReport class, or that castle.AuditReport class is not decorated with the [ActiveRecord] attribute.
```

I understand the error but how can I return a strongly typed list of a non-AR type? I've looked at what NHibernate.Transform offers but nothing stands out.

Also, is doing this bad practice?

Edit: I managed to solve it by gaining access to the underlying database session and executing my criteria from there.

```
 ISession sess = ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder().
        CreateSession(typeof(ActiveRecordBase));
    ICriteria criteria = sess.CreateCriteria<Incident>("i")
        .SetProjection(
            Projections.ProjectionList()
                .Add(Projections.Property("i.Id"), "IncidentId")
                .Add(Projections.Property("l.Id"), "LocationId")
        )
        .CreateCriteria("Locations", "l")
            .Add(Expression.Eq("l.PrimaryLocationFlag", "T"))
        .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<AuditReport>());

    return criteria.List<AuditReport>();
```

Now I'm wondering, is there another of achieving this without manually creating a new session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a class for a transformation-result, then you might need to "import" it to ActiveRecord.

Try decorating any AR class with (or maybe the AuditReport, but it might need to be a AR-decorated class):

```
[Import( typeof( AuditReport ), "AuditReport" )]
```

That would translate to the NHibernate import attribute in xml-config.

This atleast solve it when using a class construct in HQL, like this:

```
select new OrderSummary(o.Foo, count(o.Foo)) 
    from Orders o 
    group by o.Bar
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I unfortunately missed this reply while at work so I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: No matter where I use the Import attribute it still complains about referring to a non AR class. Looking at the documentation, looks like the Import attribute only affect queries written in HQL.

http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/v1rc1/manual/attributedocs/Generated_ImportAttribute.html

Comment: Oh, okay, I was afraid of that. Well, it was worth a shot. Active Record is kind of crippled in many ways, and I think you will find yourself using straight NHibernate every now and then anyhow (because you cant control 2nd level cache or use HQL with AR iirc.